# Processing --> Arduino --> Unity communication via ports

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino, serial-port, processing

**What I try to do:** Processing 3 is receiving a sort of QR code via my webcam --> it reads the value and sends it to my Arduino, Arduino successfully receives it and can now do stuff with it. Now I want to add another communication channel, Unity. I want the Arduino to send the value from the Processing to Unity.
It is easy to communicate between Arduino and Unity, but I need Processing for the webcam value.

**The problem:** Both Processing 3 and Unity make use of the same port (COM4, 9600). This will cause an IO exception in Unity saying "Access Denied"  followed by errors of the Serial port isn't open.

**Processing 3 code**

```
...
 //Open port
  String portName = Serial.list()[0];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
  myPort.write(1);
...
```

**Arduino code**

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
   ...
   Serial.begin(9600); // Start serial communication at 9600 bps
   ...
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) { // If data is available to read,
    val = Serial.read(); // read it and store it in val
  }
  //val contains now the data that was sent from Processing 3
  //Send this data to Unity:
  Serial.flush();
  Serial.println(val);
}
```

**Unity code**

```
...
SerialPort stream = new SerialPort ("COM4", 9600); //We obviously can't open this port since its already in use by Processing 3. How to fix this?
...
// Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        stream.Open(); //Throws IO exception: Access Denied error
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        string value = stream.ReadLine();
        val = int.Parse(value);
        if (val == 1) {
            //Links van arduino
            goLeft();
        }else if (val == 2) {
            //Rechts van arduino
            goRight();
        }

    }
```

We obviously can't open the port in Unity since its already in use by Processing 3. How to fix this?
*Communication stream:*

```
Processing 3 --> Arduino --> Unity
```

Eventually Unity needs to know whether you have to go Left or Right based on the QR code input on the webcam.

Comment: Well, if I understand your question correctly, that your problem is using the port which is used by Processing, then you have to close the serial port when u finish from Processing to make it available to unity.

Comment: Is there any way to do this? Since we need a constant stream of communication from processing. We use reacTiVision to read the "QR" code, processing is catching this code and sends whether we have to go right (1) or left (2)

Comment: I can't find a real solution except to make the whole process as a circle. I mean, processing => arduino => unity => processing,  then manage the serial port in this way. when you are done with it from a process, make it available for the other.

Comment: Okay, but how does Unity know when to open the port to receive the signal from arduino? Because Unity just opens the port at startup so it will become unavailable for Processing

Comment: I really can't think of a solution in this, cuz you have a hardware part in this, and it's hard to determine the process. Two solutions : First one is to use another SerialPort. The second one : is to add a wireless function to your Arduino and communicate with unity with a very basic HTML page , or whatever communication method u preferred.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I've tried to implement it. But same problem. Processing writes to the file and keeps it open, while Unity tries to read from it , but it is already opened. So I can't open the file with Unity..

Comment: Well, in this case, you can use `FileStream` and specify what you want to do with the file, you can specify `FileAccess.Read` while processing is reading/writing to file. It'll work in most cases

Comment: Thanks @kaj . I was able to fix the issue by your idea. Processing now creates an output file "data.txt" which contains values for Unity. Unity opens and reads the file by using FileAccess (else we have no permissions to read and write the file)Thank you so much for the idea! Implementation is a bit off, but it works and thats the most important thing now

Comment: Glad to hear that , For more complex process, you have to use some internet communication to keep it more simple.. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who would like to know how to solve this problem.
You can't. We have to think in another way.
Options were:

1. Close port while done processing and then open port in Unity (was not practical since we need a constant stream of instructions)
2. Leave out the Arduino and communicate between Processing and Unity (was not practical either since we need the Arduino in this case for blinkers)
3. Find another communication form between the Arduino/Processing and Unity without any ports. (Thanks to @kaj)

I've implemented the last option

- Output Processing results to a "data.txt" file
- Unity opens this file in C# with ReadAccess FileStream and reads the output and uses this

In this way we can still use the Arduino and Unity directly reads output from the Processing without a middleman.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same serial port in two concurrent applications (why do you want to use an Arduino at all?) A solution is to establish alink between applications. A network connection, using a 127.0.0.1 loopback connection, is a tried and tested way of creating that link.

As far as protocols go, you have endless options, my personal preference is to use OSC - both processing (via OSCP5) and Unity (various plugins, including my own I should really make public at some point) have decent support for messaging, but you can use many other types of links (ie. websockets)

Comment: We need the arduino for the physical indicators (left blinker and right blinker). Forgot to mention that because I thought it was irrelevant. Found an solution by sharing a txt file between processing and unity that can write and read on this file.

Comment: After carefully reading your answer again. I saw your solution quite often while searching for a solution for my case. There definitely should be an easy plugin to install this communication channel. Would be awesome if you release this plugin to help other people!